# Radio button alert dialog to return values

Tags: android, radio-button, return

in my activity i want to create a popup alert dialog box with radio buttons with few selections and i want each one of them to return some integer value when press **ok** on alert box. How can i implement this.please help.

```
long a;
    final CharSequence[] items = {" 20min before", " 40min before", " 60min before", " 1hour 30min before"};

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MovieDetailActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Set Reminder For this movie");
    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_time);
    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            if (items[item].toString().equals("20min before")) {
                a = 1 * 60 * 1000;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "In 1st", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            if (items[item].toString().equals("40min before")) {
                a = 40 * 60 * 1000;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "In 2nd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if (items[item].toString().equals("60min before")) {
                a = 60 * 60 * 1000;
            }
            if (items[item].toString().equals("90min before")) {
                a = 90 * 60 * 1000;

            }

        }

    });
```

Comment: If you can provide your code

Comment: Did you try anything? Share the code! People are not here to do your homework!

Comment: code is on top..check

Comment: it is not going in if statement

Comment: reply no now Darsh..or u doin ur homework there??

Comment: equals to equalsIgnoreCase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`equalsIgnoreCase` is used to compare `String` and `trim` is used to delete space .

```
            if (items[item].toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("20min before")) {
                a = 1 * 60 * 1000;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "In 1st", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }else if (items[item].toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("40min before")) {
                a = 40 * 60 * 1000;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "In 2nd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if (items[item].toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("60min before")) {
                a = 60 * 60 * 1000;
            }else(items[item].toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("90min before")) {
                a = 90 * 60 * 1000;

            }
```

Comment: Thanx alotttt @tiny sunlight. u saved my day.